# Inserting a Value Within an Existing Value in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that contains html links similar to this one:

```
<a href=" http://link.com"><img src="images.png"/></a>
```

I would like to insert target="_blank" into these links, like so:

```
<a href=" http://link.com" target="_blank"><img src="images.png"/></a>
```

Does anyone know how to write the query to insert (target="_blank") into each table column at the right position within the html link?

Thanks to those who answered.

Comment: What have you tried? what happened when you googled for "mysql string functions"?

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to do this, I would strongly suggest you rethink your database schema. Each link clearly contains mor than one atomic piece of information and should be spread over multiple columns

Comment: Taryn,  I'm not the programmer but the website owner and cannot afford to pay anyone at the moment.  I do have a beginner's understanding of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

`Replace()` should work for this case:

```
update table t
    set link = replace(link, 'link.com"', 'link.com" target="_blank"');
```

Comment: Not at all.  If that is your question, you should probably ask another question with more reasonable data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, but it depends on that the `<img` attribute follows the link. It does not rely on any specific link text.

```
update your_table set your_text = replace(your_text, '><img', ' target="_blank"><img')
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04982/1)

Comment: @user1667057 If you want to see what the result will be before you do the update you can simply run a `select replace(your_text, '><img', ' target="_blank"><img') from your_table` query.

Comment: @user1667057 Did you have a chance to try my answer, and if so, did it work for you?